# How do I fund BTC-e and transfer money there instantly from other exchanges?

Tags: mtgox

A few services claim they support sending money to BTC-e, but I haven't actually found the option to do it.

**Does anyone know of an instant way to send money to BTC-e or transfer money to BTC-e from another exchange like Mt. Gox?**

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no such option, hence the difference in price you see. Bitinstant used to offer the service I believe, but now it's only offered as a withdrawal option.

Comment: We are working to bring back btc-e functionality on bitinstant.com ASAP. Thanks for your patience.